# Laravel 7 Auth / fullcalendar 4 login leading to JSON Feed instead of /home

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, authentication, fullcalendar

I'm working on a little Laravel 7 backend containing a fullcalendar. I've set up the auth routine in Laravel and also integrated bootstrap and fullcalendar via npm. The calendar is being displayed in the /home view (after login). So far everything works fine. I also have a DB table for all calendar events, which are displayed in the calendar via JSON feed.

The problem I have is that everytime after the login the app does not show the /home view, as it is defined in every Controller and Middleware of Laravels auth routine. I did not change any route or redirect of the authentication process. But instead of the /home view, the app throws me directly into the JSON event feed.

This is my EventController:

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Event
     */
    protected $event;
    protected $calendar;

    /**
     * EventsController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->event = new Event();
        $this->calendar = Event::all();
    }

    public function show() {
        return $this->calendar;
    }
}
```

This is how my fullcalendar code looks like in the app.js:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import deLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/de';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
//import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
        locale: deLocale,
        defaultView: window.screen.width < 768 ? 'timeGridDay' : 'timeGridWeek',
        height: 700,
        firstDay: 1,
        buttonText: {
            today: 'heute',
            month: 'Monatsansicht',
            week: 'Wochenansicht',
            day: 'Tagesansicht'
        },
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'prev next today month agendaWeek agendaDay',
            right: 'prevYear nextYear'
        },
        allDayText: 'ganzer Tag',
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '19:00:00',
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        defaultAllDayEventDuration: {
            days: 1
        },
        events: '/getEvents'
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

And here's my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::post('/kalender', 'EventController@store')->name('event_create');
Route::put('/kalender', 'EventController@edit')->name('event_edit');
Route::get('/getEvents', 'EventController@show');
```

As I mentioned above, after login to the backend I don't see the /home view containing the calendar. What I see is the URL of the event feed ('/getEvents') with all parameters of the event feed as GET parameters:

[Browser View after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvCuh.png)

When I type /home manually into the browser, the /home view is displayed properly containing the events from DB. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: As far as I can see this issue appears to be all about your laravel route config and your login code, and has nothing really to do with fullCalendar or JavaScript. I suggest you show us your login code instead.

Comment: P.S. the screenshot is confusing. The URL it shows as visiting is called "eventFeed" but in your code above the event feed URL is showing as "getEvents". So it's unclear how these two things are actually related. You don't seem to have a route URL called "eventFeed" defined either so again it's unclear how Laravel could have redirected you here. Either there's something you're not telling you, or there's something quite wrong with your login code.